# Is TOR a Business related Environment?

Tags: discussion, questions

as I sometimes see [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/1109852/)

For my understanding, TOR could never be, and will be never a serious instrument for a Business Relationship. Sofar in my understanding, of the TOUR and Whats on Topic page, its clearly offtopic or isn't it?

Comment: There are business uses for TOR but that question is a mess and should be closed as such.

Comment: could you please explain what is the business related purpose of TOR

Comment: To allow people to circumvent censorship of provided information or services e.g. the BBC provides several .onion sites see https://www.bbcweb3hytmzhn5d532owbu6oqadra5z3ar726vq5kgwwn6aucdccrad.onion/ or to allow customers to use your site services anonymously (for the privacy minded)   e.g. the VPN provider mullvad.net (who are the underlying infrastructure for the Mozilla VPN also have a .onion site.

Comment: Facebook: https://www.facebookwkhpilnemxj7asaniu7vnjjbiltxjqhye3mhbshg7kx5tfyd.onion/

duckduckgo: https://duckduckgogg42xjoc72x3sjasowoarfbgcmvfimaftt6twagswzczad.onion/

There are likely man more

Comment: [It's "Tor", by the way, not "TOR"](https://matt.traudt.xyz/posts/2021-02-22-tor-spelling/).

Answer (score 5):

Providing an onion site could very well be a legitimate business activity, as examples in the question comments show.  Running a Tor relay or bridge *might* be business-related.  As such, a question asking about how to configure or run Tor would not necessarily qualify for automatic closure.

It's worth noting that the question you referenced was closed for lack of clarity, not because it wasn't business related.